# Trigger gulp tasks based on parameter

Tags: javascript, triggers, task, gulp

Is it possible to trigger dependent tasks based on the parameter flag?

Example:

```
//task one will be triggered like this from the command line
gulp one --flag

//gulpfile
gulp.task('one', function() {
  if(gutil.env.flag) {
    //run task two
  } else {
    //run task three
  }
});

gulp.task('two', function() { });
gulp.task('three', function() { });
```

The closest for this requirement was `gulp.run` but it is now deprecated. Most of the references were pointing to `gulp.watch` but I don't want to watch any file. I simply have to look for the parameter and trigger tasks accordingly.

Edit 1: A colleague pointed me to [run-sequence plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/run-sequence). Though it serves my purpose, there is a warning posted on the site "**Be aware that this solution is a hack, and may stop working with a future update to orchestrator.**"